# Does acumatica has console version of installer?

Tags: acumatica

I want to create docker image of Acumatica. For this purpose I need console version of installer of Acumatica. Does Acumatica has console version of installer?

Comment: Can't you run the installer in quiet mode? You can view available MSI options by running "installer.exe /help"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not Sure this is exactly what you want, but there are instruction on how to use the Command Line tool to install and do maintenance of an Acumatica Website in the S100 course and on the [Acumatica Help Website](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(16))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=b4770bd0-deda-403a-aeb6-e3ddbbbfabb1)

It use the ac.exe with parameter do deploy an new installation.
The complete list of parameters can be found in both of the place mentioned before.